# How to sort data to both directions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, indexing

I need to sort table by "distance" from a value.

---

For example:
In DB:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

What I need (for some n value):
if `n = 3`:

```
3
2
4
1
5
6
```

if `n = 5`:

```
5
4
6
3
2
1
```

Comment: What's the rule for each sorting? It doesn't look like "*sorted*"

Comment: It sorted by increasing the difference between n and the value in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between two values can be defined as the absolute value of the difference between those values.

Thus, if your column is called e.g. `value`, you can use the [`ABS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) function as follows, e.g. for the value `3`:

```
SELECT value FROM my_table ORDER BY ABS(3 - value);
```

Which will give you this result:

```
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|     3 |
|     2 |
|     4 |
|     1 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
+-------+
```

Or for the value `5`:

```
SELECT value FROM my_table ORDER BY ABS(5 - value);
```

Which will yield:

```
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|     5 |
|     4 |
|     6 |
|     3 |
|     2 |
|     1 |
+-------+
```

If you want to do the sorting in PHP, you can just do:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$n = 3;
usort($array, function($x, $y) {return(abs($n-$x) - abs($n-$y));});
```

Answer (score 2):

As you said in your comment:

> It sorted by increasing the **difference between n and the value** in the table

Than do exactly that. :) E.g. for `n=3`:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable ORDER BY ABS(3 - value) ASC, value ASC;
```

First order will sort by distance  between `n` and `value`, the second will sort by `value` ascending, when the distance is the same.

[ABS()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) MySQL function stands for absolute value. You want to use it, because the difference equal to e.g. `2` and `-2` is the same distance and it's equal to `2`.

The second order condition I assumed basing on your examples. It's not required if you don't care.

Answer (score 0):

In php you can do the following:

```
$array = (1,2,3,4,5,6);

//Find index
$key = array_search(3, $array); // $key = 2;
$up = true; //flags for traversal
$down = true;
$result = array();

for($i=1; $i<= count($array); $i++)
{
     if(!empty($array[$key - $i]))
     {
         $result[] = $array[$key - $i];
     }

     if(!empty($array[$key + $i]))
     {
         $result[] = $array[$key + $i];
     }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Or just `usort($array, function($x, $y) {return(abs(3-$x) - abs(3-$y));});`